# Disabling LRO using ethtool?

Tags: linux, networking

My NIC driver does not support H/W LRO but emulates LRO in the driver. Now GRO (which is a linux network stack feature) can be disabled using 'ethtool -k ethx gro off'. Is that available for LRO as well? i know most distros have either LRO or GRO. So if LRO is disabled using ethtool does it imply turning off the H/W LRO feature or the LRO emulation feature that i do in my driver?

Comment: For readers: `LRO` stands for [Large receive offload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload).  This is a method to reduce the numbers of interrupts of network cards by fast transmits, but [there](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=772317) [are](http://support.hp.com/de-de/document/c02639123) [known](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=483646) [issues](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2010-0178.html) [with](http://goo.gl/OSXO1Y) [routing](http://goo.gl/XdvwD3) or bridging

Comment: And just fyi, there are issues with this in non linux protocol stacks too. As the checksum is not recalculated (at least with gro this was the case) certain network stacks like cisco's tcp will check the checksum and not be lenient like linux tcp is and ignore the error.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if your ethtool is new enough.

On my Ubuntu box (Natty Narwhal), "man ethtool" and "ethtool --help" show that LRO is controlled just like GRO; i.e.

```
ethtool -K ethX lro off
```

Run "ethtool --help | grep lro" to see if yours supports it.

Answer (score -3):

```
ethtool -k ethx lro off
```

It should prevent the system from performing lro.  However, many of the drivers which still use LRO are broken and do not honor ethtool.

http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg149013.html

Comment: This is wrong, `-k` (lower case) shows the settings. Nemo's answers is the proper usage.